# 16.04 How to fix mplayer which suddenly went silent after automatic software update

Tags: 16.04, sound, mplayer

`mplayer` has been working for a long time, until a recent automatic software update with a system restart.

Now it makes no sound but otherwise looks normal.

Command is:

```
mplayer Ding.mp3
```

---

On the terminal screen it still looks the same, counting as it plays, yet there is no sound.

Did the usual manual commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade    (and it did some upgrading)
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Yet no difference.  It looks fine but makes no sound.

Tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

and it told me it was already the latest version.

---

Interestingly, `espeak` is still working fine:

Example:

```
espeak "System backup script is starting"   (in a cron script)
```

comes through loud and clear.

---

**So the hourly cron script in question, which looks like this:**

```
mplayer Ding.mp3
echo "\`$(date +%-I)\` O'Clock!" | espeak
```

**is silent for a couple of seconds then says "4 O'Clock"**

**when up until today it used to first ding then announce the hour**

---

The problem seems to be specific to `mplayer` and it does not matter whether it is in `cron` or in the terminal.

**Question:  In Ubuntu 16.04 How to fix mplayer which suddenly went silent after automatic software update?**

Comment: this may not help *(it helps me when I do wrong things with keyboard/mouse)* but I load `pavucontrol` (pulse audio volume control) and check for muted applications *(it allows you to change volumes of specific apps)*

Comment: You hit it on the head. pavucontrol allowed me to fix it. In the Advanced section under the digital output it had unchecked the MPEG box. It is working again now. Great advice, my friend. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`guiverc`'s comment above gave me the information I needed to get it fixed.

First right-clicked on the speaker in the upper right and made sure it was set for the `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` device.  (I use a USB sound dongle)

Then to `pavucontrol` in the terminal.

--> `Output Device` tab --> `Audio Controller Digital Stereo` --> Advanced

Checked the MPEG box.

Now it works again.

**MANY THANKS, guiverc**

Comment: In my case, I need to go `Playback` tab and adjust the Mplayer section volume bar in dB.